# How to get Facebook access_token using the OAuth2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-oauth

I have integrated Facebook login into my web application.
I am getting the "code" parameter when i am requesting by sending the required details, and then i have to exchange the obtained "code" for an "access_token".For that i am making a HTTP GET call to :-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
   &client_secret={app-secret}
   &code={code-parameter}
```

The response which i am getting is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, X-FB-Rev: 1624746, Pragma: no-cache, Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, Facebook-API-Version: v1.0, Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT, X-FB-Debug: XM3kCi/2T3bPfe2/QRmn08rBwHTn7SkY8iADhkirVCZ4HOKPGH45zK8WWq0/5+KDFdUWwIn7blnjYfy1py6jrQ==, Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 06:25:17 GMT, Connection: keep-alive, Content-Length: 245]
```

In the response i am not getting the access_token parameter which i need for further proceeding into the application.
According to Facebook docs response should look like

```
access_token={access-token}&expires={seconds-til-expiration}
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to get the solution for the answer.Facebook gives the access_token but it needs to be retrieved using entityutils object and then converted into UTF-8 type.here is the code which worked for me and i am able to get the access_token object from the Facebook API response.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(FBAPI_HITURL.toString());
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

responseString will contain the response in the format "access_token={access-token}&expires={seconds-til-expiration}"